# How to add google sheet excel column values to dropdown in power apps

Tags: powerapps

I am completely new to Power Apps. Please help me.

I have a google sheet excel. In that sheet only one column(text values) is available. I need to add that cto dropdown. How can I add?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a sheet like this one:

[image: Sheet with names]

Then you can add a connection to that sheet, and reference it in the `Items` property of your control.

The screen capture below shows how you can do that.
[image]